# Wacom tablet for writing equations and explaining in a video format

Tags: drawing-tablet, wacom

Hi I would like to ask you what type of Wacom should I buy if I want to make a video for my students that explain simple mathematics?

What I mean is that I do not need it to draw or anything that has to do with graphic designing (I know the more options the tablet has to offer, the more expensive it gets. I don't want that.) I only need it to make a very good quality video of mathematics while I talk through a microphone in order to explain.

What model of Wacom do you suggest I buy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For what you need to do, any kind of graphic tablet should be just fine: don't need to bother looking for pressure levels and other specific functions. The Wacom Intuos has a dotted drawing area that can help when drawing straight lines and diagrams or if you want to do a decent job looking at the tablet instead of the screen. I'd go with this, or with the cheapest option (even if not Wacom)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Do you suggest other brand than Wacom?

Comment: Another question: Is this what you mean? https://www.amazon.de/Wacom-CTH-490AK-S-Stift-Tablett-Softwaredownload-Essentials/dp/B013ATUFUC/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1498833145&sr=8-3&keywords=wacom+intuos

Comment: This last link is what I was talking about. I think this is the top tier choice for what you need to do, but I am not excluding that you could choose other brands since there are tablets that with half the price could suit your needs. Wacom is a great choice tho.

Comment: Thank you Stefano. In case you know other brands that do the same job, let me know.

Comment: You are very welcome. Huion and Trust offer some lower price alternatives, check them out. Good luck with your purchase!

Comment: I was thinking, if while writing on the tablet I placed the side of my palm on the tablet, will this affect the writing process? Because it is difficult to write with a pen on a flat surface without placeing your hand on that surface.

Comment: No, just the pen affects the tablet surface. Your hand will have no response. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Surface would work well with that and detects your hand when you use the pencil so it doesn't affect the writing.

Comment: He asked for a Graphic/Drawing Tablet not an Laptop/Tablet-PC